# What is the purpose of this answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

The [answer given from soos](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/allow-comment-homepage-urls-without-http/7479#7479) to [Allow comment homepage URLs without http://](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/allow-comment-homepage-urls-without-http) is suggesting what already reported in an answer given four months before; the only difference is that, apart being less detailed, the new answer adds a link that is irrelevant.

What is then the purpose of the new answer? Is it spamming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like spam to me. I deleted the link, for now.